# Netflix Hystrix - HystrixObservableCommand asynchronous run

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-boot, netflix, hystrix

I have some basic project that has like four calls to some external resource, that in current version runs synchronously. What I would like to achieve is to wrap that calls into `HystrixObservableCommand` and then call it asynchronously.

From what I have read, after calling `.observe()` at the `HystrixObservableCommand` object, the wrapped logic should be called immediately and asynchronously. However I am doing something wrong, because it works synchronously.

In the example code, the output is `Void`, because I'm not interested in output (for now). That is also why I did not assigned the Observable to any object, just called `constructor.observe()`.

```
@Component
public class LoggerProducer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoggerProducer.class);

    @Autowired
    SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    private void push(Iterable<Message> messages, String topic) throws Exception {
        template.convertAndSend("/messages/"+topic, messages);
    }

    public void splitAndPush(Iterable<Message> messages) {

        Map<MessageTypeEnum, List<Message>> groupByMessageType = StreamSupport.stream(messages.spliterator(), true)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Message::getType));

        //should be async - it's not 
        new CommandPushToBrowser(groupByMessageType.get(MessageTypeEnum.INFO),
                MessageTypeEnum.INFO.toString().toLowerCase()).observe();
        new CommandPushToBrowser(groupByMessageType.get(MessageTypeEnum.WARN),
                MessageTypeEnum.WARN.toString().toLowerCase()).observe();
        new CommandPushToBrowser(groupByMessageType.get(MessageTypeEnum.ERROR),
                MessageTypeEnum.ERROR.toString().toLowerCase()).observe();

    }

    class CommandPushToBrowser extends HystrixObservableCommand<Void> {

        private Iterable<Message> messages;
        private String messageTypeName;

        public CommandPushToBrowser(Iterable<Message> messages, String messageTypeName) {
            super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("Messages"));
            this.messageTypeName = messageTypeName;
            this.messages = messages;
        }

        @Override
        protected Observable<Void> construct() {
            return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Void>() {

                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super Void> observer) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i ++ ) {
                            LOGGER.info("Count: " + i + " messageType " + messageTypeName);
                        }
                        if (null != messages) {
                            push(messages, messageTypeName);
                            LOGGER.info("Message type: " + messageTypeName + " pushed: " + messages);
                        }
                        if (!observer.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            observer.onCompleted();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        observer.onError(e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

There are some pure "test" code fragments there, as I was trying to figure out the problem, just ignore the logic, main focus is to make it run async with `.observe()`. I do know that I may achieve that with standard `HystrixCommand`, but this is not the goal.

Hope someone helps :)
Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was found:

> "Observables do not add concurrency automatically. If you are modeling
>   synchronous, blocking execution with an Observable, then they will
>   execute synchronously.
>
> You can easily make it asynchronous by scheduling on a thread using
>   subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()). Here is a simply example for wrapping a
>   blocking call with an Observable:
>   https://speakerdeck.com/benjchristensen/applying-reactive-programming-with-rxjava-at-goto-chicago-2015?slide=33
>
> **However, if you are wrapping blocking calls, you should just stick
>   with using HystrixCommand as that’s what it’s built for and it
>   defaults to running everything in a separate thread. Using
>   HystrixCommand.observe() will give you the concurrent, async
>   composition you’re looking for.**
>
> HystrixObservableCommand is intended for wrapping around async,
>   non-blocking Observables that don’t need extra threads."
>
> --  Ben Christensen - Netflix Edge Engineering

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hystrixoss/g7ZLIudE8Rs